# How to pick elements in d3 with a specific property value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having items painted using d3 on browser. I want to highlight some of them depending on their property. For example, I have groceries, soaps in which soap elements will have type as `[for_bath (OR) for_cloth_wash]`. I want to select those elements specific to `for_bath` in all soaps and groceries combined and painted together on same screen.

How ?

Also, my another doubt is document.getElementById() is not working inside d3's selections code. Am I true or an oversight ?

**EDIT**

```
var data = {"soaps":{"lux":"bath", "cinthol":"bath", "rin","cloth_washing"}, 
            "shoes":{"valentine":"teens", "bootie":"kids", "kuuch":"kids"}};

//  Now I want to show all bath soaps highlighted, may be with a circle around them.
var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .selectAll(".items")
            .data(data).enter()
            .append("circle")
            //  highlighting styles
;
```

***Here I want to select bath soaps and round them up.***

Answer (score 4):

You haven't given us any code, so I'm going to guess here. What you're probably looking for are [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). So if you want to select elements which have the attribute `soap` set to `for_bath`, you would do

```
d3.selectAll("[soap=for_bath]");
```

This is for DOM elements only. If you're talking about data elements, then you can use the [`.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
data.filter(function(d) { return d.soap == "for_bath"; });
```

Regarding your second question, I'm not sure what you mean. The arguments to `d3.select()` or `d3.selectAll()` are DOM selectors, so `document.getElementById()` doesn't make sense here. You can however certainly use it other functions:

```
d3.selectAll("something").each(function() {
  d3.select(this); // the current element
  document.getElementById("something"); // another element
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time. I will improve my question with some code.